# OK to rebase a remote branch if I am the only one using it?

Tags: git, rebase

I have a long-term (one-month) development branch that I pushed remotely so that I could work on it from a different computer.  But I am the only person who has ever used it.  I had to set it aside to work on other things.

Now, a month later I am resuming the work but the mainline has changed quite a bit.  Normally if there were just a local branch I would rebase it branch on master and continue so as to keep the final history looking clean, but I've read in many places that you should not rebase a branch that you've pushed remotely.

(The plan is to finish this work on the development branch and merge it into master.  Then I would delete the development branch completely but locally and remotely.)

Is there any danger to rebasing a remote when you're the only person ever using the branch?  Is it a better idea to just merge master in the remote work on it and then merge back to master?

Comment: The only problem in moving things around comes when you are not the only user, or if you have multiple machines working on the same branch.

Comment: And for the case where other people are involved, there are two issues to [watch out for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76984332/23118), accidentally discarding commits pushed by others, and the potential "recovery" needed by other participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the description of the problem is a little bit longer.... it is a problem if you rebase *and* other people **use** that branch. If you are one developer in a team of 100 and you are working on a feature branch that no one will use until it is merged into a common branch (dev, main, whatever) then it is perfectly fine to rebase or use any other tricks on it.