# Is it safe to rebase remote branch if nobody based work on it?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-remote, remote-branch

I want push my personal local branch for code review with my peer. My peer doesn't will merge this branch. After code review, I want rebase my personal branch in master branch, and push master branch. Is safe?

The [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) says:

> **Do not rebase commits that exist outside your repository and that people may have based work on.**

I expect this won't be a problem, since nobody based work on this branch. I am correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct → [OK to rebase a remote branch if I am the only one using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486586/ok-to-rebase-a-remote-branch-if-i-am-the-only-one-using-it)

Comment: The criterion is "nobody uses the branch as basis for futher work", not "nobody has merged the branch". You may want to change the title of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is a bit confusing, and you need to be very clear about it before you use `git rebase`:

> After code review, I want rebase my personal branch in master branch, and push master branch.

The normal wording is "rebase branch A *onto* branch B". What this really means is "create a new version of branch A, *as though* you had developed it starting from branch B".

Branch B is *not changed* by this action.

The reason I'm going over this is to make clear what the warning means:

> Do not rebase commits that exist outside your repository and that people may have based work on.

The commits you are rebasing are *branch A* - the branch that is going to *change* as result of the rebase.

So there are two very different scenarios:

- "I want to rebase some-personal-branch *onto* master, and then push some-personal-branch to GitHub/BitBucket/wherever" - this is probably OK: nobody will have *based work on* some-personal-branch
- "I want to rebase master *onto* some-personal-branch, and then push master to GitHub/BitBucket/wherever" - this is almost certainly **not OK**: your colleague might have *based work on* master, and things will get confusing

---

A smiple rule of thumb I like to use is "who owns this branch?"

- A branch that I own is one for a task that I'm working on alone; I should be safe to do what I like with it - rebase, amend commits, etc
- If this is a branch that *someone else* owns, I should not do anything to it other than look at it - I should not even base any work on it
- If this is a shared branch that people will base work on, *nobody* owns it, and commands like `git rebase`, amending commits, etc, should only be used in rare "emergency" situations

Comment: Your note about my wording help me so much. Many thanks.